# can y1 and y1+(t,t) be solutions for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the question is:

- a. can $ y_1$ and$y_1 + (t,t)^{T}$ be solutions for ODE of the form $ \dot {\overrightarrow y}=A(t)\overrightarrow y + \overrightarrow b(t) $
  where A(t) is a continous matrix and $\overrightarrow b(t)$ is a continious vector.
- b. same question about $\overrightarrow y_1, 2\overrightarrow y_1$

I have more questions of the same but I think understanding the basic concept will be enough for me to solve it.

I thought about showing that the wronskian is equal to zero but I'm not sure that's the way to do it...

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote dimension of $\vec{y}$ by $d$.

a) If $y_1$ is  solution then it is a vector. But if we have sum $y_1 + (t,t)^{T}$ then $y_1$ in 1-dimensional since $(t,t)^{T}$ is 1-dimensional.

Hence for all $d \ge 2$ the answer is negative as $y_1 + (t,t)^{T}$ doesn't have sence.

Now consider the case $d=1$ and suppose that $y_1$ and $y_1 + t^2$ are solutions. Thus
${y'}_1 = A(t) y_1 + b(t)$ and ${y'}_1 + ( t^2)' = A(t) (y_1 + t^2) + b(t)$. It follows that $2t = A(t) t^2$. Thus $A(t) = \frac2{t}$.

For example, if $t \in [1,2]$ we may take $b = 0$, $A(t) = \frac2{t}$, then $y(t) = t^2 + const$, so the answer is positive.

If $t \in \mathbb{R}$ then the answer is negative since $A(t) = \frac2{t}$.

Maybe by $y_1$ you meant the first coordinate of $\vec{y}$, which is $d$-dimensional.

In this case the answer is: "sometimes yes, but in general no", as it was shown in the previous example in case $d=1$.

b) The answer is: "sometimes yes, but in general no".

Suppose that $y_1$ and $2 y_1$ are solutions. Put $d=1$ for simplicity. Thus
$y'_1 = Ay_1 + b$ and $2y'_1 = 2Ay_1 + b$. Thus $b = y'_1 - Ay_1 = \frac{b}2$ and $b=0$.

So in case $d=1$ your statement is true iff $b = 0$ for all $t$. Thus the answer to b) is: "sometimes yes, but in general no".

Comment: thank you so much for this! my question is, why should I look at the solution $y_1 + t^2$ 
and I'm sorry I didn't mention it, It turns out the question is about 2 dimensional vectors such as (t,t) so $y_1$ is actually $(y_1, \dot y_1)^{T}$

Comment: @AmitDavidi, what do you mean by "I should look at the solution $y_1 + t^2$"? It you don't want to look at this solution, it's normal) So what do you mean?